System Error While Running any Flutter Project

[Fatal Error] flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-a18df97ca57a249df5d8d68cd0820600223ce262.pom:2:90: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

The above error I am getting whenever I am trying to run my flutter project .Tried every step that I saw on chat gpt but still unable to resolve . So if someone has encountered this before and know how to solve it Please help!.
I tried cleaning the cleaning the cache memory of gradle,upgrading the flutter,rebuilding everything but unable to resolve this issue.
app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.shop_app_flutter"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.shop_app_flutter"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true 
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

flutter doctor -v:

Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.2538], locale en-IN)
Flutter version 3.24.5 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework revision dec2ee5c1f (3 weeks ago), 2024-11-13 11:13:06 -0800
Engine revision a18df97ca5
Dart version 3.5.4
DevTools version 2.37.3
Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
Android SDK at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
All Android licenses accepted.
Chrome - develop for the web
Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
Android Studio (version 2023.1)
Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
VS Code (version 1.95.3)
VS Code at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
Flutter extension version 3.102.0
Connected device (4 available)
sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 15 (API 35) (emulator)
Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.2538]
Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 131.0.6778.109
Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 131.0.2903.70
Network resources
All expected network resources are available.
Doctor found issues in 1 category.


you can updates about this issue here : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/159927

The issue was with the version of the flutter(3.24.0) . New version of the flutter has resolved this issue .Flutter 3.27.0 • channel is a stable version.
